# How to structure string data with key value pair

Tags: typescript, angular7

structure i need :

```
[{ label:'Year',
   type:'year',
   options:[{ year:'2019' },{ year:'2018' },{ year:'2017' },{ year:'2016' }] },
 { label:'Make',
   type:'make',
   options:[{ make:'Ford' },{ make:'BMW' }] },
 { label:'Model',
   type:'model',
   options:[{ model:'Freestyle' },{ model:'Mustang' }] },
 { label:'Location',
   type:'location',
   options:[{ location:'Manheim' },{ location:'Adessa' },{ location:'Manheim, Georgia' }] }]
```

service data i get is :

```
{ location: ["Manheim", "Adessa"],
  model: ["Lincoln", "Ford"], 
  series: ["s-160", "B-140"], 
  year: ["2019", "2018", "2017"] }
```

please help me out for structure i need

Comment: You need to be clearer about what your input is, and the code you've tried already.

Comment: Data i get from service :{location: ["Manheim", "Adessa"]
model:  ["Lincoln", "Ford"]
series:  ["s-160", "B-140"]
year:  ["2019", "2018", "2017"]}

Comment: You can try to iterate over the given properties and `map` every property to an element of the expected data structure - `Object.keys(src).map((e) => ({ type: e }))`

Comment: can you give the code to execute . Iam new in this.

Comment: how to attach options array in each mapped object ?

Comment: @madhukanduri Good question. In JavaScript you could write `options: src[e].map((o) => ({ [e]: o }))` but not in TypeScript.

Comment: Thanq so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `map` every property of the source structure to your target structure. To dynamicly access the properties for the the `options` the properties should be literals instead of `string`. Therefore you can use [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```
const src = {
    location: ["Manheim", "Adessa"],
    model: ["Lincoln", "Ford"],
    series: ["s-160", "B-140"],
    year: ["2019", "2018", "2017"]
}

const keys = ['location', 'model', 'series', 'year'] as const
const result = keys.map((e) => ({
    label: e.replace(/^./, (c) => c.toUpperCase()),
    options: src[e].map((o) => ({ [e]: o })),
    type: e
}))
```